# Changes in one list is reflected in second list as well in html

Tags: html, css

I am having a lot of problems figuring out what went wrong in this code. I am creating a footer for my website which consists of two unordered lists. The problem is whenever I am making some changes in my first list then automatically the changes are reflected in the second list as well. What's the problem?

```css
    .footer1{
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #348AC7, #7474BF);
        width: 100%;
        height: 350px;
        display: block;
    }
    .footer2{
        padding-left: 200px;
        padding-top: 40px;
        width: 400px;
       display: block;
        
    }
    .footer2 h1{
        color: white;
    }
    .footer2 p{
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .footer3{
        padding-left: 1000px; 
        display: block;
    }
    .footer3 h1{
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        display: block;
    }
    .footer3 ul,li{
        list-style-type: none;
        
        display: block;
    }
    .footer3 ul{
        display: block;
    }
    .footer3 a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        font-size: 20px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 200px;
        right: 30px;
        display: block;
    }
    .footer3 a:hover{
        color: red;
    }
    .footer2 ul,li{
        color: black; 
        display: block;
      
    }
    .footer2 ul{
        display: block;
    }
    .footer2 a{
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        
    }
    .footer2 a:hover{
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="footer1">
    <div class="footer2">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <p>The cartzilla E-commerce website is a very popular online shopping site where people get to buy all the things just by sitting at home.The list of categories that we have are electronics,furniture,home appliances,fasionable clothes etc.</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">+91-72088101541</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">kevinkhimasia13@gmail.com</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

   <div class="footer3">
        <h1>Quick links</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: better you can define your ul by calling the difference class

Comment: And what example of a change do you make on one of the lists that is creating this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seen is that changes to footer2 get reflected in footer3, they are not independent.

If we look at the CSS and extract two similar definitions we see that:

```
.footer3 ul,li{
    list-style-type: none;
    
    display: block;
}
```

comes before:

```
.footer2 ul,li{
        color: black; 
        display: block;
```

}

In CSS, the cascading means that something coming after (normally) takes precedence over something coming before.

Now, `.footer3 ul,li` means 'style any ul in .footer element and any li **anywhere**.

To make it style the li in .footer3 you need to write as:

```
.footer3 ul, .footer li{
    list-style-type: none;
    
    display: block;
}
```

To be on the safe side, do the same for the declarations for footer2 as you don't want to affect other li elements in the document whose definitions might have come further up the style sheet cascade.